Unable to send security code to Teltonika EYE Sensor using bleak in Python
I’m trying to connect to a Teltonika EYE Sensor device and send a security code using Python with the bleak library. I’ve successfully connected to the device but cannot send the security code to the sensor and read data. Below is the relevant code.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

# Define the MAC address of the device and the security code
MAC_ADDRESS = "7C:DX:X4:XX:FX:6X"  # Device's MAC address
SECURITY_CODE = "123456"  # Security code

# UUIDs based on the sensor documentation
SERVICE_UUID = "00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" 
PASSWORD_CHAR_UUID = "e61c0008-7df2-4d4e-8e6d-c611745b92e9"  # Command characteristic UUID
DATA_CHAR_UUID = "00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"  # Read characteristic UUID

async def connect_and_read_from_device():
    async with BleakClient(MAC_ADDRESS, timeout=60.0) as client:
        if await client.connect():
            print(f"Connected to {MAC_ADDRESS}")

            try:
                # Send security code
                await client.write_gatt_char(PASSWORD_CHAR_UUID, bytes(SECURITY_CODE, 'utf-8'))
                print(f"Security code {SECURITY_CODE} sent to the device")

                # Read data from the device
                data = await client.read_gatt_char(DATA_CHAR_UUID)
                print(f"Data read from the device: {data}")

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Failed to interact with the device: {e}")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect to the device.")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(connect_and_read_from_device())

According to the Teltonika EYE Sensor documentation  documentation link , the PASSWORD_CHAR_UUID is e61c0008-7df2-4d4e-8e6d-c611745b92e9, and the characteristic I want to read from has the UUID 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. More UUID setting

I can connect to the device, but when trying to send the security code, I get the following error:
Connected to 7C:D9:F4:10:F7:6B
Failed to interact with the device: [WinError -2147483629] The object has been closed

Has anyone faced a similar issue or know what could be causing this? Any help would be appreciated!
